# Heroku: module not found create-react-app

Tags: heroku, webpack, module, create-react-app

I have a project I am building using create-react-app. When I try to deploy to Heroku, I get the following error:

```
./src/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-redux' in '/app/src'
```

I thought it was something to do with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46458485/heroku-webpack-react-module-not-found-when-building-on-heroku-but-found-locall/51931525#51931525)  but after installing that plugin, I still get the errors.

#### package.json

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.5",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.8"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1"
  }
}
```

My Webpack config contains the following line:

```
isEnvDevelopment && new CaseSensitivePathsPlugin(),
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`react-redux` and `redux` itself are listed in your `devDependencies` so they're not included when you deploy to Heroku. `devDependencies` are for things you need in development but not in production. Examples might be linters, editor plugins, live reload tools, etc.

You definitely need these to be `dependencies`, not `devDependencies`. Move them to that section, update your lock file with `npm install` or `yarn`, commit, and deploy again.

I'm not familiar with `case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin` is, but you might need to move that too. (Though it looks like you might only have installed it to try to fix the issue you're asking about. You might be able to just remove it.)

Comment: Thanks Chris, I got it working by following these instructions (funnily enough!): https://medium.com/quick-code/deploying-production-build-of-react-app-to-heroku-2548d8bf6936. Thanks again 